# How can I hide the bottom bar when pushed but stay in the main view Controller

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

I want to hide the bottom bar when I press a button or a cell ( in a table )  in the main view controller to push to another view controller and **not when I press a button in the bottom bar** .
And when I back to that main view controller **I want get back the bottom bar**

I tried the code in the main view controller : **hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = true**

But when I press on an item in the bottom bar and get back to the main view controller the bottom bar is disappear, and the same when I go to new view controller (by push from the main view controller), the bottom bar in the main view controller disappears.

Answer (score 9):

So far I can see you have to hide the bottom bar already in the prepareForSegue func in your first view controller. The code below works fine on my side:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "yourSegue" {
        if let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow() {
            if let destVC = segue.destinationViewController as? TargetVC {
                destVC.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = true
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Question is old, but first in google search.

From interface builder, use checkbox "Hide Bottom Bar on Push":

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In your pushed View controller :

```
   init() {
            super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
            self.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = true
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Since PeiweiChen's answer didn't work for me, i came up with this instead:

(One has to put this in to the pushed View Controllers file)

```
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        self.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = true
    }
```

PS.: This is Swift 2.0